# C++ Templates - code usage, size of binary

Tags: c++, templates, code-size

I'm wondering about code size of template code.
Please consider following code

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
public:

 vector(size_t size) :
 {
     array = new T[size];
 }


 uint32_t push_back(T value)
 {
  ... adding value to array and possible array realloction..  
 }

private:
 T * array;
}
```

When i have two vector instances,

```
vector<float> v1;
vector<int> v2;
```

will it be compiled to binary with two `push_back` implementations

```
push_back(float)
push_back(int)
```

or only one, or something else?

Is it possible to reduce code size with templates instead of creating separated classes for `float` and `int` vector?

Comment: Compile with optimizations on and generate a map file.  Different compilers/linkers will do things differently.

Comment: It depends on your compiler, machine, optimization level, and the moon cycle...

Comment: So there is no general rule ?
How about GCC?

Comment: Don't assume bloat, compilers are pretty good at optimizing. And if they can't optimize, you can still [extract the common parts, and keep the template for type safety](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Thin_Template). But verify there is any bloat first.

Comment: For example MSVC implements COMDAT folding: if 2 or more sections of code are identical only 1 is put into the executable.  If for example `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)` then the majority of the code generated for the 2 vectors will be the same and only 1 copy will be put into the final executable.  Note this is a link time operation so looking at the assembly listing generated by the compiler will not give you the full picture.

Comment: Templates do not allow to reduce *machine code* size compared to the separate non-template implementations (assuming that they are doing the same things). However they allow to reduce *source code* size eliminating duplication and reducing the risk of bugs. Also you should never assume that compilers are good at optimizing as some other comment suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes and functions instantiated from templates do not have any relation between them at runtime and thus functions will be duplicated.

Some compilers will optimize away shared/duplicate code but this optimization's scope is wider than template instances.

Note that even if the code looks the same it may trigger different function calls when certain operators are used.

This is especially visible for pointer containers like `std::vector<int*>` and `std::vector<char*>`, you will get different functions for both although their behavior is practically identical.

To summarize, templates are excellent at reducing code size and but creating many different instances will bloat your binary.

Comment: Um, comdat folding in msvc will eliminate functions with identical assembly, so your claims are false in general.

Comment: @tobi303 - fixed.

Comment: @Yakk - I mentioned compiler optimizations in the 2nd paragraph. De facto, a lot of template generated code will produce different assembly, I wrote that in section 3